# Link dinamico para redirigir al Dashboard en el front-end

Tags: wordpress, redirección, enlace

Tengo una pagina en `wordpress` basada en el *theme* `Workreap` que es un *marketplace* tipo *freelancer*.

Todo iba de maravilla hasta que me tope con el redireccionamiento al dashboard de los usuarios registrados, ya que, quise crear un botón en la barra del menú que fuera visible si el usuario esta logueado llamado **Mi Cuenta** y le coloque el link de la pagina dashboard `https://demos.planetalogo.com/pippol/dashboard` pero no funciona.

Sin embargo cuando el link es `https://demos.planetalogo.com/pippol/dashboard/?ref=insights&identity=3` si muestra el dashboard...

Pero es un link que posee el id del usuario.

¿Cómo puedo crear un link que tome automáticamente el Id del usuario y me redirija al *DashBoard*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con algo como esto

```
    // Obtenemos al usuario actual
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    // Creamos el enlace dinamico
    $dashboardLink = bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/pippol/dashboard/?ref=insights&identity=' . $current_user->ID;
    // Hacemos un echo de la variable $dashboardLink que contendrá nuestro enlace
    echo $dashboardLink;
```

Básicamente construyes en enlace dinámicamente y le pasas el id del usuario actual, sin tener que hacerlo de forma manual.